# Concatenate two dataframes with different row indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate two data frames of the same length, by adding a column to the first one (`df`).

But because certain `df` rows are being filtered, it seems the index isn't matching.

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['customer.csv'].decode('utf-8')), sep=";")
df["Margin"] = df["Sales"]-df["Cost"] 
df = df.loc[df["Margin"]>-100000] 
df = df.loc[df["Sales"]> 1000] 
df.reindex()
df
```

This returns:

[image]

So this operation:

```
customerCluster = pd.concat([df, clusters], axis = 1, ignore_index= True)
print(customerCluster)
```

Is returning:

[image]

So, I've tried `reindex` and the argument `ignore_index = True` as you can see in above code snippet.

Comment: assign the operations you do: df=df.reindex()

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that too, but it doesn't work. The result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. If anyone encounters the same problem, the solution I found was this:

```
customerID = df["CustomerID"]
customerID = customerID.reset_index(drop=True)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

So, basically, the indexes of both data frames are now matching, thus:

```
customerCluster = pd.concat((customerID, clusters), axis = 1)
```

This will concatenate correctly the two data frames.